# An Android client SDK for communicating with OAuth 2.0 other than AppAuth

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, openid, appauth

I am using Android-AppAuth in my app for AD B2C login and unlike in iOS-AppAuth, there's no nonce value included when making authorization requests in Android-AppAuth.

I would just like to ask if there are any Android SDKs like Appauth but with nonce value included in the authorization requests.

If there aren't, is it possible to manually send a nonce value to an AppAuth authorization request?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup additional parameters to `AuthorizationRequest`. 
`AuthorizationRequest` implements Build patter. It has `setAdditionalParameters(Map<String, String> additionalParameters)` method where you can specify any parameters for authorization request.

Example from demo AppAuth-Android demo app:

```
    Map<String, String> additionalParams = new HashMap<>();
    additionalParams.put("nonce","<some_nonce_value>");

    AuthorizationRequest.Builder authRequestBuilder = new AuthorizationRequest.Builder(
            mAuthStateManager.getCurrent().getAuthorizationServiceConfiguration(),
            mClientId.get(),
            ResponseTypeValues.CODE,
            mConfiguration.getRedirectUri())
    .setScope(mConfiguration.getScope())
    .setAdditionalParameters(additionalParams);
```